# How to edit standard class of android?

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi-direct

I am trying to build an app which acquired information from WiFi Access point, however, this information is not a standard information. i am transmitting additional information from the access point. Now to receive this information, i need to modify the class "WifiInfo." I am not sure how can I do it. I tried googling it, but no luck.

Is it possible to do this?
If yes, How,
Can I do this using any alternate way?

Thanks in advance for your help. :)